# Counting Problem (permutations) with making words?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $21$ consonants and $5$ vowels in a language. Each word starts with a consonant and is followed by $1$ or more pairs of vowel-consonants (e.g. 'piv', 'cadit', etc.) No vowel or consonant can be repeated once it is used.

Here's how I did it:

$5! \cdot P(21, 6) = 4688409600$ different words.

I am wondering if my method is right.

Comment: You have not taken into account the fact that there are one or more pairs of vowel consonants.  Also, do you mean that a word is formed using only an initial consonant and vowel-consonant pairs with no other consonants?

Comment: I have taken that into account. If you expand this, you would get 21 (first letter of every word is a constonant) * [5*20](first pair) * [4 * 19] (second pair) * [3 * 18] (third pair) * [2 * 17](fourth pair) * [1 * 16] (last possible pair b/c there are no more vowels left)

Comment: Then you only did the case in which there are five vowel-consonant pairs.  You need to consider cases in which there are fewer than five such pairs.

Comment: I just mean that there are 21 consonants available. Every word starts with a consonant. After that, there are only vowel-consonant pairs. You can not reuse the same consonant or vowel again.

Comment: Doesn't that contain cases in which there are fewer than 5 pairs?

Comment: No, it does not.  There are $21 \cdot 5 \cdot 20$ words with only one vowel-consonant pair.  You need to add this to your result, as well as the number of words with two, three, or four vowel-consonant pairs.

Comment: We would add it right? not multiply?

Comment: Yes, you add the results of the five cases since they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: So the final answer would be 4,990,215,300 words

Comment: That is correct.  You can answer your own question so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are 21 consonants and 5 vowels, and none of them can be used more than once, we will have up to 5 pairs after the first consonant. We have to take in account of all possibilities of pairs (1 pair, 2 pairs, 3 pairs, 4 pairs, 5 pairs).

1 Pair: 21 * 5 * 20

2 Pairs: 21 * 5 * 20 * 4 * 19

3 Pairs: 21 * 5 * 20 * 4 * 19 * 3 * 18

4 Pairs: 21 * 5 * 20 * 4 * 19 * 3 * 18 * 2 * 17

5 Pairs: 21 * 5 * 20 * 4 * 19 * 3 * 18 * 2 * 17 * 1 * 16

You would add all of these possibilities for pairs up and it would equal a final answer of 4,990,215,300